# How to calculate mean squared displacement (MSD) value as function of Tau (lag-time)

Tags: computational-physics, diffusion, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm doing a research on Brownian motion (in 2D) and I want to calculate the MSD values in order to find the diffusion coefficient $D$.

However, online I find different approaches on how to calculate it.
The two that stood out to me were:

1. From your coordinates calculating the absolute distance $r$ and then calculating $(r(t) - r(t+\tau))^2$ for all pairs of data-points separated by $\tau$ and taking the mean.
2. First taking the difference of your coordinates as vectors for all pairs of data separated by $\tau$ and then calculating the square of the absolute value and taking the mean. So $|\mathbf{x}(t) - \mathbf{x}(t+\tau)|^2$

Here [Mean square displacement python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31264591/) they do number 1 for example, here [Basic Concepts](https://web.mit.edu/savin/Public/.Tutorial_v1.2/Concepts.html) number 2. And on Wikipedia [Mean squared displacement (MSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_displacement) in the first section they do something similar to number 2 but average over a number of particles, which gives the impression the "Mean" part from MSD comes from calculating this for several particles.

The way I understand it is that with method 1 you are kind of figuring out how the radius develops over time if you say that the particle travels some distance from a given origin (the starting position). Whereas with method 2 you see how much a particle travels over its path, and how fast it does that on average for a time frame of tau.

I'm guessing in order to make use of the relationship MSD $= 4Dt$, you want to make use of method 2. But I'm really not sure. Maybe someone can explain how to calculate the MSD as function of tau.

I also used this video [A Look Into Mean Squared Displacement](https://youtu.be/yZ7zHg7goBc?feature=shared&t=194) to understand how the MSD value is calculated. This is however in the 1D case but the position on the $y$-axis is also negative. If the position would be the absolute distance then this wouldn't make sense so I think that's also a hint method 2 is the appropriate method.

Comment: You've to do 2. And MSD = $E\left[|\boldsymbol{x}(t+\tau)-\boldsymbol{x}(t)|^2\right] = 4 D \tau$

Comment: Do you need only analytical or also numerical stuff?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119577/25301, probably others too

Comment: What do you mean by $E[...]$ (E square brackets)? @basics

Comment: expected value. Every realization of a random process is different, in principle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSD should be the vector difference, which means Option #2. You can see [this on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_displacement#Definition_of_MSD_for_time_lags), for example, where the MSD for a time lagged scenario is given in terms of the vector equation $\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta)-\mathbf{r}(t)$.

If you note, one of the "Linked" questions on that SE post, [this one specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738376/how-to-optimize-mean-square-displacement-for-several-particles-in-two-dimensions?noredirect=1&lq=1), actually discusses the calculation of the MSD of the lagged scenario (i.e., your specific problem) and uses the  full vector difference for the time lag. They also discuss (in some terribly written code) how to compute it significantly faster using [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), which might also be an interest to you.